# Is Power BI supports SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

We have lots of SSRS reports. We are planning to migrate those to Azure but found it is not supported. Does Power BI support SSRS reports? If yes, can we use Power BI reports in asp.Net application like we can load SSRS reports in report viewer in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Power BI has what Microsoft is branding [Paginated Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi). Its functionality within Power BI to support the RDL format from SSRS. You will need Power BI premium to get that feature though.

As far as using report view in .Net I am not sure. Since this is a rather new feature of Power BI there isn't a wealth of resources about it. I was able to find this documentation about [embedding a paginated report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports-customers).

Answer (score 0):

[Power BI Premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-what-is) does support SSRS reports, called [Paginated Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi) to separate them from the standard Power BI Reports.
However Paginated Reports will have some [feature gaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi#limitations-and-considerations), for example [sub-reports has only just been implemented](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/subreports-now-available-for-paginated-reports-in-power-bi/) in Paginated Reports.

In terms of designing paginated reports, the Report designer is the same interface and style. You can embedded both the Power BI and the Paginated reports into a asp.net application, by using the [Power BI Embedded API](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html)